# Is the variable garbage collected or not?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, d={}):
        self.x = []
        d['any'] = self.x

    def append(self, i):
        self.x.append(i)

x = X()
x.append(3)
x.append(13)
x.append(123213)
print(x.x)  # show [3, 13, 123213]
```

The question is, what happens to `d`? Is it garbage collected? If it is, how does `x` still exist?

Comment: Why would `d` be garbage collected? You still have `x` and `X` and `X.__init__` in memory. `x` references `X`, and `X` references `__init__` and that function references `d`.

Comment: Also the `x` instance references `x.x`, the list, so there is no reason for *that* list to be garbage collected. `x.x` does not reference `d`, that relationship goes the other way.

Comment: Is it possible to refer to `d` then?

Comment: Last but not least, `d` is a *function default* and stored in the function object.

Comment: Yes, you can reference `X.x.__defaults__`

Comment: Regardless of whether or not `d` was done, that would just reduce the reference count of the variables it reverse to, like `x` in this case.  Only when a variable's reference count is 0 is it available for garbage collection

Comment: Don't do this.  Never use mutable types as the defaults.  Every instance of class `X` will share the same `d` dict.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Never say never. A mutable type as a default value is perfectly valid, *if* you know that you want to accumulate values across function calls. The trick is knowing when it is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `d`, you really mean the `dict` object that serves as the default value for that parameter. There is a "hidden" reference to this `dict` that prevents it from being garbage collected.

```
>>> print x.__init__.__defaults__
({'any': [3, 13, 123213]},)
```